Is it possible to get projection from $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is not evenly apart but pre-image is?

Consider the points $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$ marked consecutively along a line $l' \in \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(0,0)\}$ with spacing $|x_{k+1} - x_k| = 2^{k-1}$ for $k = 1,2,3$. Could the points $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ represent the image of $4$ equally spaced points along a different line $l \subset \mathbb{R}^2 - \{0\}$ under a projection of
$l$ to $l'$ from $0$? Further, suppose $|x_{k+1} - x_k| = 2^{k-1}$ for $k = 1,2$ only. Select $|x_4 - x_3|$ such that the consecutive points $x_1, \cdots, x_4$ are the projective image of $4$ equally spaced points.

Attempt: So far I can only think that this is intuitively possible. Suppose on a cartesian plan we are at $(0,0)$ (as the question asks), and there are two lines $l$ and $l'$ parallel to the y-axis. Our points $x_1, \cdots, x_4$ located below the x-axis and lie on $l'$ and are the images of a projection from points on line $l$. Because our projection gets distorted due to us observing the points at $(0,0)$ I can vaguely imagine that such as situation is possible. But is there a more mathematical way to show this? Or show it is not possible?
As for the second part of the question (which I think actually confirms the first part is possible), my attempt is to compute that $|x_2 - x_1| = 1$ and $|x_3 - x_2| = 2$ which gives the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$ consecutively. But again, how can that help us determine how to select $|x_4 - x_3|$ to make the pre-image equally spaced?

Projection preserves the cross ratio. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio

@EthanBolker Sorry I do not understand fully. What does it have to do with preserving cross ratio?

Calculate the cross ratio of the equally spaced points and the cross ratio of the projected points. They must be the same. I haven't done the algebra, so this is only a hint that may help you answer your question.

@EthanBolker Can you please get me started on the computation? I am still a little confused on cross ratio. To my understanding, we can find the distance between $x_1$ to $x_2$ and $x_2$ to $x_3$, and we wish to find the distance between $x_3$ and $x_4$. However, the cross ratio needs 4 values to compute. Also, how would we compute the cross ratio of the projected points? I don't think we were given anything in the question. Thank you.

If I am reading the question correctly you want to know if four points on a line spaced this way
A   B   C   D
  1   1   1

can project to four points on another line with spacing
A'   B'      C'           D'
   1     2          4

No, they can't. The cross ratio for the first set
is
$$
\frac{CA \times DB}{CB \times DA} = 
\frac{2 \times 2}{1 \times 3} = \frac{4}{3}
$$
while for the second set it's
$$
\frac{3 \times 6}{2 \times 7} = \frac{9}{7}.
$$
You can place $D'$ to make the projection possible. Let $D'C' = x$ and solve
$$ 
\frac{3 \times (x+2)}{2 \times (x+3)} = \frac{4}{3}
$$
for $x$. The answer is $x = 6$.

I see. This is for part one of the question. By orientation, you mean that the projection can be rotated as well, and doesn't have to be displayed like your answer shows, right? But regardless, the cross ratio should be preserved under projection, but it is not according to this calculation. Hence, it is not possible.

@IcedTea Correct. It does not matter where you put the figure in the coordinate plane.  I edited the question to include a solution to part 2.

Thank you very much. This has been very helpful :)
